# Summarize values in recursive function

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I have following permutation code

```
void permute(Matrix *m,int *array,int i,int length) { 
 
     if (length == i){
         printA(array,4);
         return;     
      }

     int j = i;
     for (j = i; j < length; j++) { 
         swap(array+i,array+j);
         permute(m,array,i+1,length);
         swap(array+i,array+j);
     }
     return;
}
```

Its working fine but i want to execute a function to every permutation of array which return a value and add them together.

**Example : [1 2 3 4] -> function(array) -> 12 , [1 3 2 4] -> function(array) -> 13 => 13+12 = 25** (This will be determinant calculator)

Tried this:

```
 double cnt = 0;
 if(lenght == i){
     cnt += function1(array,4);
 }
```

But it just show distinct values not summarize them. Where is should repair the function?

Comment: Try `static double cnt = 0;`? or is `cnt` a global variable?

Comment: yeah static variable working. I thought on this but never tried. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Post answers as answers; don't edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since recursion calling function at every permutation i need to use **static** global counter to summarize values. So i just put somewhere `static double cnt = 0;` and working fine.